# Updated - Having trouble making a circled button in android

Tags: android, xml, button

I'm trying to use an image as a button. The image is an oval/circle, so when I set it as the background there's basically a black box with the image on top of it. How can I fix this?

This is the fragment main xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
tools:context="com.zarwanhashem.thatwashard.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/hardButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/hard_button_clickable"
    android:background="@null"
    android:onClick="hardButton"/>
```

This is the hard button xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/hard_button_img" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/hard_button_img" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/hard_button_img"/>

</selector>
```

Here's the problem in the app:
http://i.gyazo.com/a7f3b25341ebf4146d294df1f5660e99.png

I've tried setting background to null and setting src to my image file. Nothing changed.

Thanks.

e; Here's the actual PNG: http://tinypic.com/r/av3cli/8

e; Still looking for help with this!

e; Bump. Does no one know what's going on?

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    public void hardButton (View view) {
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.thatwashard);
        mp.start();
    } 

}
```

e; Bump. Still can't figure this out. Look at the commments in the first answer to see the actual picture.

e; Bump. @Lazy Ninja

e; Bump

Answer (score 0):

I inspected your image in GIMP. The background is not transparent. It's solid white.

Correct your image file, then use the following in your ImageButton.

```
android:src="@drawable/hard_button_clickable"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

---

**Additional**

I've looked at your revised actual image. It's a jpg.
If you want to take advantage of transparency you should use a png.
In general png is the preferred format for android.

A couple of additional points. `android:text`, `android:textColor`, `android:textSize` are not supported in `ImageButton`.

Comment: How? This is what I see on GIMP: http://gyazo.com/316bcb158cc1f15220432d52fdd87c6e.png

Comment: That's not what you get if you download the image from the url you supplied. Try it. Besides that, If you're image definitely is transparent in your ide, then use the xml I've supplied. should work

Comment: The URL is a screenshot of the image in windows photo viewer, it isn't the image itself. So it has the blue background from the photo viewer.

Comment: Upload the actual png, and update your question with the new link.

Comment: done, but I had to get rid of the picture with windows photo viewer because I'm only allowed to have 2 links

Comment: did you check the picture?

Comment: Sorry had an end of month project deadline. Check my edited answer.

Comment: it's saved as a PNG on my computer: http://gyazo.com/92de63e19a33977e431e96af610e1d4f.png  I even tried converting it online just in case and it labelled at as a PNG. About the tags, they're from the old button I was using. I forgot to remove them, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Setting your view `scr="@drawable/hard_button_clickable"` and  `android:background="@null"` should solve your problem.
And you can not have text in an ImageButton
.

```
   <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/hardButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/hard_button_clickable"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="hardButton"/>
```

Comment: Nothing changed. This is actually getting ridiculous, it seems like no one can figure this thing out. Is there any chance that it doesn't have to do with the xml I've posted?

Comment: Just for checking set your relative layout background to white

Comment: I edited in the new code into the first post. Is that what you meant? If yes, it didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you post hard_button_clickable.png somewhere. I want to test it. The xml I posted should have worked.

Comment: did you check the pic?

Comment: Yes I checked. And I tested with the xml I provided above. It displays correctly in my device. Are u changing the ImageButton properties programmatically somewhere?

Comment: Not that I know of. I updated the fragment main xml and added the main activity code above so that you can check.

Comment: Your source code looks fine. It is pretty weird. Which device are you testing on? What is the build target( minSDK, targetSDK )? By the way, when I downloaded your image it was in JPG format, I renamed it to PNG. Have you yours in PNG format?

Comment: Yes, it's saved as a PNG. I'm using a Nexus 4. I don't remember what I set the SDKs as. How can I check?

Comment: In manifest file check for     <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion=""
        android:targetSdkVersion="" />

Comment: does that have to do with my problem?